# Question about Hungerford's definition about cardinality

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

In Hungerford's Algebra, he firstly defines that equipollent is a relation between two sets $A$, $B$ if there exists bijective $f:A\rightarrow B$, then proves

> Equipollence is an equivalence relation on the class of all sets.

then

> Definition 8.2: The cardinal number (or cardinality) of a set $A$, denoted $|A|$, is the equivalence class of $A$ under the equivalence relation of equipollence. $|A|$ is an infinite or finite cardinal according as $A$ is an infinite or finite set.

As he states in the next paragraph,

> Cardinal numbers are frequently defined somewhat differently than we have done so that a cardinal number is in fact a set (instead of a proper class as in Definition 8.2)

I think I understand the definition and understand that the cardinal number  is always a proper class.

But later the author asserts:

> Property (iii) The cardinal number of a finite set is the number of elements in the set.

Here I can't understand it. By his definition, the cardinal number of a finite set should be an equivalence class by equipollence on the class of all sets, so how can it be a number? or it is how a number defined?

From the definition, I can only conclude that $|A|=|I_{n}|$ for some $n$, where $I_{n}=\{1,2,...,n\}$. So the property (iii) is true only when the "number" is actually a proper class? Hungerford does not clearly state what a "number" is, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of paragraphs above this property, in a version of Hungerford on Google Books [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=t6N_tOQhafoC&lpg=PA16&ots=cTKfnwT6Sm&dq=hungerford%20Property%20(iii)%20The%20cardinal%20number%20of%20a%20finite%20set%20is%20the%20number%20of%20elements%20in%20the%20set.&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=false) , there is this explanation:

[image]

In other words, Hungerford states that he is identifying the integer $n$ with the cardinal number that is the equivalence class under equipollency of sets with $n$ elements.

Comment: Is there any difference between "identify" and "define"? Because in ZFC the numbers are defined by sets, and this equation means the proper class $|I_{n}|=$a number. It is very weird.

Comment: @EricYewenSun You'll have to accept that Hungerford's natural number $2$ (a certain proper class) is not the (von Neumann) natural number $2$ widely used in connection with ZFC (the set $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$). They also differ from Zermelo's $2$ (which I believe was $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$) and very probably from the $2$ you had in mind when you were a small child just learning to count (which was probably neither a set nor a proper class).

Comment: @Andreas: And also $2$ of the natural numbers as a model of PA ($SS0$) vs. $2$ of any ring, e.g. $\Bbb{Z,Q,R,C}$, which is $1+1$.